# 3 divs positions across a webpage

Tags: html, css

I am in need of some help with some divs.

I currently have

```
<body>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="main"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
</body>
```

and I am trying to make it so the following occurs.

Left div aligns against left side of the screen, while right aligns to the right. The main then would be 1000px wide and be in the middle of the page

| Left Div | Main div 1000px wide | Right div |

I have seen this done using tables but I'd rather use a div to create my layout.

the main div will have other divs inside it for contents so I will also need the left and right divs height being the same as the main div.

Anyone able to help?

Regards,
Mason

Comment: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/category/C10/  you can look at this web-page or this page : http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can do table-like layouts using `divs`. Check out the [`table-*` values for CSS `display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).

http://jsfiddle.net/MVSjr/

### HTML

```
<div class="table">
    <div>
        <div id="left">test</div>
        <div id="center">test</div>
        <div id="right">test</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#left {
    background:#F00
}
#center {
    background:#0F0;
    width: 300px;
}
#right {
    background:#00F
}
.table {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
.table > * {
    display:table-row;
}
.table > * > * {
    height: 200px;
    display:table-cell
}
```

Comment: using of `*` is not good for performance.. use comma if there are more elements with same stylings.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for *three column layout* for your web page. Three column layout can be either `fixed` or `fluid`.

In Fixed layout all the three columns would have the fixed width and when you re-size your browser screen, they will display with horizontal scroll bar.

In Fluid layout all the three columns would have width in percentage of screen width. Here is an example of *three column fluid layout*.

```
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="main"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

and CSS

```
div{
    display:inline-block;
    height:500px;
}
.left,.right{
    background:red;
    width:15%;
}
.main{
    background:green;
    width:70%;
}
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zgrR8/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a constant distance between the left / right divs to the main one, you'll have to specify it. My advise is to specify a page width, say 1300 px, and then split div's measures as you need (e.g: 150px for the left div, 1000px for the middle, 150px for the right. And then center the wrapper div to the page.

```
.wrapper{
  width: 1300px;
  margin: auto;
}
.left{
  width:150px;
}
.main{
  width:1000px;
}
.right{
  width:150px;
}
```

You might also want to consider making it responsive either by specifying width in % if your content allows it or by specifying break-points in media-queries, but it's just a thought...